how can we start/stop & create/delete sagemaker studio resources based on domain and user profile so that i can make a scheduler to trigger them?
I have tried to automate to start/stop and create/delete sagemaker studio resources i.e jupyter notebook, endpoint but i can do it individaually not at once using domain and user_profile. can anyone help me with what is the steps that i need to follow to achieve this.
i have tried setting cron individually for each resources in sagemaker studio but i could not trigger start and stop or create and delete with just  user_profile and domain which is available in sagemaker studio.
my target was to schedule the start and stop or create and delete of resources in sagemaker studio  to save cost by just starting when needed and stopping when not needed.
